# Datamapper::collection getting data from it and putting it into erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, collections, datamapper

I'm trying to get data out of this datamapper object and then putting it into a loop and getting the data out of the object that way, but it doesn't seem to be working, this is the code I have:

```
@user = User.get(session[:user])
@polls = []
polls = Poll.all(:user_id => @user)
polls.each do |poll|
  pollname << poll.name
  @polls << pollname
end
```

and in my erb file:

```
<% @polls.each do |poll| %>
    <p><%= poll %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks what you want is:

```
@user = User.get(session[:user])
@polls = Poll.where(user_id: @user.id).all.collect { |p| p.name }
```